# How can I make a Giant with full diamond armor (Protection IV) riding a bat with spawner

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was watching YouTube when I found a giant zombie that I liked. I wanted it to have full diamond armour with Protection IV, riding a bat + have a mob spawner for it

Comment: Unless things have changed since I last used command blocks, you cannot give a giant armor (well you can, but it won't appear which I presume is the point)

Comment: Ok can you make it ride a bat?

Comment: @DBS  Note that armour will appear on giants when the 1.8 update is released.

Answer (score 3):

The pure summoning should be (1.7):

```
/summon Giant ~ ~1 ~ {Equipment:[{},{id:313},{id:312},{id:311},{id:310}],PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}],Riding:{id:"Bat",PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}]}}
```

or 1.8:

```
/summon Giant ~ ~1 ~ {Equipment:[{},{id:diamond_boots},{id:diamond_leggings},{id:diamond_chestplate},{id:diamond_helmet}],PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}],Riding:{id:"Bat",PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}]}}
```

The code for the spawner (1.7):

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Giant,SpawnData:{Equipment:[{},{id:313},{id:312},{id:311},{id:310}],PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}],Riding:{id:"Bat",PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}]}}}
```

or 1.8:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Giant,SpawnData:{Equipment:[{},{id:diamond_boots},{id:diamond_leggings},{id:diamond_chestplate},{id:diamond_helmet}],PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}],Riding:{id:"Bat",PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}]}}}
```

I think it is obvious that you need a commandblock. Please try the summon-cmds to test if this is what you want.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great first answer. I'm not 100% sure, but I think OP wanted the armor pieces to have a Protection IV enchantment, rather than the giant and the bat having is as an effect, which seems to be what these commands do.